# How to calculate the mean of only one channel for a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, tiff, geotiff

I have a numpy array of shape (66,67,4). When I do np.mean(imarray) it calculates the array mean but takes all channels into consideration. I want to calculate the mean of only channel 1 and channel 3, separately.

I am doing this since I have a .tif file and it contains certain attributes in each band and they are essentially independent from each other so I need to calculate means separately

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: `np.mean(im[...,1])` and `np.mean(im[...,3])`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of channel 1 - assuming you meant the first channel:

```
np.mean(array[:, :, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. And channel 3 would be np.mean(array[:,:,2])?

Comment: @AhmedTech Yes, again I'm assuming you're aware of zero-based indexing